# how to interate a list of columns names in purrr::map to create new columns in R

Tags: r, purrr

I want to perform an action against a list of columns in a dataframe using map() but I get an error which I can't understand, can anyone help?

I want it to recycle through the list of columns names in `vec` and to subtract against the values in column d, in dataframe `df`.

update: an answer was provided with across (which works) however i need to do this with `map()` not `across()`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a=seq.Date(from=ymd("2021-01-01"),to =ymd("2021-12-31"),by = "day"),
       b=seq.Date(from=ymd("2020-01-01"),to =ymd("2020-12-31"),by = "day"),
       c=seq.Date(from=ymd("2019-01-01"),to =ymd("2019-12-31"),by = "day"),
       d=seq.Date(from=ymd("2018-01-01"),to =ymd("2018-12-31"),by = "day")
)


vec <- c("a","b","c")

map(vec,~transmute(df,d-.x))
```

Comment: You mean `transmute(df, across(all_of(vec), ~ d - .x))` ? BTW, 2020 was a leap year and example data generation will fail due to incompatible column sizes.

Comment: Or is the desired result list of 3 tibbles, each with a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the `across`

I updated the data to have dates from march instead of Jan, since feb has different # days and we will not get the dataframe generated

## data

```r
df <- tibble(a=seq.Date(from=ymd("2021-03-01"),to =ymd("2021-12-31"),by = "day"),
             b=seq.Date(from=ymd("2020-03-01"),to =ymd("2020-12-31"),by = "day"),
             c=seq.Date(from=ymd("2019-03-01"),to =ymd("2019-12-31"),by = "day"),
             d=seq.Date(from=ymd("2018-03-01"),to =ymd("2018-12-31"),by = "day")
)


vec <- c("a","b","c")
```

### code

```r
df %>% mutate(across(vec, ~ d-.x))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: oh okay, i know why its because I'm using arrow and duckdb object types and  for some reason the pattern above doesn't work for it

Comment: however, can I ask how to do this with map? I know across works but it would be helfpul to understand the map() function too?